# Separate String from path using regex

Tags: regex

I have a file in this path

```
D:\ebook\comic\Author,_Title_of_Book_(http://google.com).cbz
```

I need to separate the string using regex and get Author, Title, and URL. 
The text output should be

```
Author
Title_of_Book
http://google.com
```

So far i have

```
([^\\]+)\.[^\\]+$
```

Which will get me the file only.

Comment: Does it have to be regex?  In most languages this would probably be easier without it.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be regex.

Comment: Can you explain the regex requirement? I'm not sure you're going to be able to cause three lines of output to happen with underscores converted to spaces all inside a single regular expression. Maybe you can define the constraints a little better.

Comment: I made some changes. All i want are 
Author, Title_of_Book, http://google.com selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

```regex
^[^,]*\\([^,]*),_([^(]*)_\(([^)]*)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- separate the string using regex and get Author, Title, and URL

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/aB8zQ6/1

**Sample text**

```
D:\ebook\comic\Author,_Title_of_Book_(http://google.com).cbz
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [15-21] `Author`
2.  [23-36] `Title_of_Book`
3.  [38-55] `http://google.com`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \\                       '\'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,_                       ',_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^(]*                    any character except: '(' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^)]*                    any character except: ')' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE @RoYoMi posted a far superior answer, but as I'd already done the work, here you go.

Since you only tagged regex here, I didn't know what language you needed to get this working in. I whipped up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r6y4of91/1/) test for this example. Here is the code.

```
<p>
  <input type="text" id="val" value="D:\ebook\comic\AuthorLastName_FirstName,Title_of_Book_(http://google.com).cbz" style="width:100%;" />
</p>
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="url"></div>
<script>
    var val = document.getElementById("val").value;

    var name = /\w+(?=[,])/.exec(val).toString().replace(/[_]/g, " ");
    var title = /\w+(?=[(])/.exec(val).toString().replace(/[_]/g, " ");

    var url = /((http)(s?)[:](\/\/))(.*?)(?=[)])/i.exec(val)[0].toString();
    //Better suited with a look behind like this:
    //var url = /(?<=[(])(.*?)(?=[)])/.exec(val).toString();
    //But JS doesn't support look behinds.

    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = url;
</script>
```